# Prepopulate Envelope External Source ID for Powerform

Tags: docusignapi

I have managed to pass values to my powerform except for External Source ID.  Anyone know what the syntax is for doing this?

Is it EnvelopeField_DSFSSourceObjectId=???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct to me. However, if you know what object it's going to write data back to I would replace DSFSSourceObjectId with ##SFObjectName

So something like EnvelopeField_##SFLead=

Comment: Here's my scenario: I have a Powerform that people sign online and I am passing AccountID parameters to that with no problems at all and in my DS connect settings, I have it mapped to Account ID (SF) and AccountID (custom tag). But I want users to be able to send that same powerform from SFDC but using the custom send agreement code is not allowing me to pass any parameters to it.

Comment: So in my connect settings, my where clause says Account ID (SF) and AccountID (custom tag) works for my online powerform but NOT for my SFDC sends.

Comment: If I change my connect settings where clause to say Account ID (SF) and Envelope Source ID(docusign), then this works for my SFDC sends but not for my online signers

Comment: Rickey, when I tried your suggestion, it started asking for email and name of signer 1.  Do you know what those field names are so I can prepoulate them as well?